# Create specified list of dictionaries with list comprehensions

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have list of dictionaries:

```
test_users = [{'user': 'ADMIN0', 'privilege': 'ADMIN', 'auth_protocol': 'SHA_512'},
          {'user': 'ADMIN1', 'privilege': 'ADMIN', 'auth_protocol': 'SHA_256'}, \
          {'user': 'MONITOR12', 'privilege': 'MONITOR', 'auth_protocol': 'SHA_512'}, \
          {'user': 'MONITOR13', 'privilege': 'MONITOR', 'auth_protocol': 'SHA_256'}]
```

and wanna to create a new list with dicts that contains unique values of 'privilege' and 'auth_protocol'. For example:

```
selected_users= [{'user': 'ADMIN0', 'privilege': 'ADMIN', 'auth_protocol': 'SHA_512'},
          {'user': 'MONITOR13', 'privilege': 'MONITOR', 'auth_protocol': 'SHA_256'}, \
```

Restrictions:

1.'privilege' can never be duplicated,

2.(optional) 'auth_protocol' can be repeated only if all possibilities are used(in this case it can be another privilege with 'auth_protocol' in 'SHA_256' or 'SHA_512')

My attempt to solve the problem:

```
test_users_copy = test_users
selected_users = []
random_user = random.choice(test_users_copy)
# Add randomly chosen user to the list
selected_users.append(random_user)
test_users_copy.remove(random_user)

for test in selected_users:
    selected_users += [user for user in test_users_copy if (user.get('privilege') not in test.get('privilege')) and (user.get('auth_protocol') not in test.get('auth_protocol'))]
```

Comment: How do you decide which dictionary to pick in case of duplicate `privilege` or `auth_protocol`

Comment: Add all elements to an intermediate dictionary with keys `(privilege, auth_protocol)` and convert its `values()` to a list.

Comment: Privilege should always be unique(if there is no more unique 'previlege' list is done), however value of 'auth_protocol' should be as diverse as possible, so I would check the current values in selected_users and on that base make a choice.

Comment: So the dict with `ADMIN1` and `MONITOR12` will be removed? Also your textual description doesn't make much sense, it is better if you can provide a concrete output

Comment: Code will be in the function each time it will works on copy of all created users. The purpouse of this is to get random users with their parameters (representated by dicts)Final output will contains list of dictionaries with unique privilege, so the totall count of dics in list will be equal unique privileges. I posted example output before(selected_users). When it comes to delete dict after being added its obviously because same privilege cant be used again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to select users with different `privilege`s and `auth_protocol`s:

```
>>> test_users = [{'user': 'ADMIN0', 'privilege': 'ADMIN', 'auth_protocol': 'SHA_512'},
... {'user': 'ADMIN1', 'privilege': 'ADMIN', 'auth_protocol': 'SHA_256'},
... {'user': 'MONITOR12', 'privilege': 'MONITOR', 'auth_protocol': 'SHA_512'},
... {'user': 'MONITOR13', 'privilege': 'MONITOR', 'auth_protocol': 'SHA_256'}]

>>> privileges, auth_protocols = set(), set()
>>> [tu for tu in test_users if not (tu["privilege"] in privileges or tu["auth_protocol"] in auth_protocols) and not privileges.add(tu["privilege"]) and not auth_protocols.add(tu["auth_protocol"])]
[{'user': 'ADMIN0', 'privilege': 'ADMIN', 'auth_protocol': 'SHA_512'}, {'user': 'MONITOR13', 'privilege': 'MONITOR', 'auth_protocol': 'SHA_256'}]
```

The list comprehension is pretty straightforward: if `tu["privilege"]` or `tu["auth_protocol"]` was seen, skip the dict; otherwise add them to the seen privileges and auth_protocols (`not x.add(y)` is always `True`: this is one of the very few cases where a side effect is acceptable in a list comprehension).

But this won't return a dict by privilege if you don't have different protocols. Worse, the choice is always the same.

To stick with your optional requirement, you need something more sophisticated.

Let's build a dict `privilege -> auth_protocol -> users`:

```
>>> users_by_ap_by_privilege = {}
>>> for tu in test_users:
...     users_by_ap_by_privilege.setdefault(tu["privilege"], {}).setdefault(tu["auth_protocol"], []).append(tu)
>>> users_by_ap_by_privilege
{'ADMIN': {'SHA_512': [{'user': 'ADMIN0', 'privilege': 'ADMIN', 'auth_protocol': 'SHA_512'}], 'SHA_256': [{'user': 'ADMIN1', 'privilege': 'ADMIN', 'auth_protocol': 'SHA_256'}]}, 'MONITOR': {'SHA_512': [{'user': 'MONITOR12', 'privilege': 'MONITOR', 'auth_protocol': 'SHA_512'}], 'SHA_256': [{'user': 'MONITOR13', 'privilege': 'MONITOR', 'auth_protocol': 'SHA_256'}]}}
```

We want to take one user per `privilege` (condition 1), and the max possible different ̀`auth_protocol`s (condition 2).

We can have the available `auth_protocol`s by `privilege`:

```
>>> ap_by_privilege = {privilege: users_by_ap.keys() for privilege, users_by_ap in users_by_ap_by_privilege.items()}
>>> ap_by_privilege
{'ADMIN': dict_keys(['SHA_512', 'SHA_256']), 'MONITOR': dict_keys(['SHA_512', 'SHA_256'])}
```

For Python < 3.6, we need to set once for all the order of `privilege`s (won't do any harm in Python >= 3.6):

```
>>> privileges = list(ap_by_privilege)
>>> privileges
['ADMIN', 'MONITOR']
```

It's now easy to build all combinations of `auth_protocol`s:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> prod=list(itertools.product(*[ap_by_privilege[p] for p in privileges]))
>>> prod
[('SHA_512', 'SHA_512'), ('SHA_512', 'SHA_256'), ('SHA_256', 'SHA_512'), ('SHA_256', 'SHA_256')]
```

(Note that the tuples contains the `auth_protocol`s associated with every `privilege` in the list `privileges`, in the same order) We can now affect a duplicate count to every combination:

```
>>> import collections
>>> tuples_by_dup_count = {}
>>> for t in prod:
...     tuples_by_dup_count.setdefault(max(collections.Counter(t).values()), []).append(t)
...
>>> tuples_by_dup_count
{2: [('SHA_512', 'SHA_512'), ('SHA_256', 'SHA_256')], 1: [('SHA_512', 'SHA_256'), ('SHA_256', 'SHA_512')]}
```

Now, we take the minimal key of this dict, ie the tuples with the minimal number of duplicates (condition 2):

```
>>> ts = tuples_by_dup_count[min(tuples_by_dup_count)]
>>> ts
[('SHA_512', 'SHA_256'), ('SHA_256', 'SHA_512')]
```

Then we choose a combination of `auth_protocol`s:

```
>>> import random
>>> t = random.choice(ts)
>>> t
('SHA_256', 'SHA_512')
```

And use it to select a random user by `privilege`/`auth_protocol`:

```
>>> [random.choice(users_by_ap_by_privilege[p][t[i]]) for i, p in enumerate(privileges)]
[{'user': 'ADMIN0', 'privilege': 'ADMIN', 'auth_protocol': 'SHA_512'}, {'user': 'MONITOR13', 'privilege': 'MONITOR', 'auth_protocol': 'SHA_256'}]
```